# How many iterations of the function $k →k−\left\lceil k^{1/2}\right\rceil$ are needed before k drops to 0?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity

[Complexity question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaonU.png) says that since $k \leq\frac{1}{4}n^2 \Rightarrow k−\left\lceil k^{1/2}\right\rceil \leq \frac{1}{4}(n-1)^2$, we have that it is $O(\sqrt{n})$. But I cannot see how this works?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What, in particular, do you not understand about it?

Comment: I can see how the algebra works in the source I posted, I don't however see how this gives $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: That image has $\frac{1}{4}$ everwhere, not $\frac{1}{2}$. I think the result should be $O(\sqrt{k})$, not $O(\sqrt{n})$, since $n$ isn't a natural part of the question. Probably a typo

Comment: Ah my bad with the typo in my question; but do you feel the image is wrong as well? I'm not sure whether the $n$ referred to at the end is the same as the $n$ at the start?

Comment: There is no $n$ at the start. That's the confusing part. There is an internal reference to a variable $n$, but it is an auxiliary value. Unless they really mean that $n$ is the first value. Again, I think it is a typo.

Comment: So, given it is a different variable, how does it show that $f(k)=k-⌈\sqrt{k}⌉$ is $O(\sqrt{k})$?

Comment: Me either, since it is f(x) = x - Sqrt[x]  and f(x) is O(x)
but it is true if k<n^2/2 then k-Sqrt(k)<(n-1)^2/2
Solve the inequality to see it algebraically

Comment: Maybe imagine a few examples. Suppose $k=100$, then the iterations of $k$ are $100,90,81,72, \dots$, for $19$ iterations. If $k=10000$, then you have: $10000,9900, 9801,9702,\dots$ for $199$ iterations. For $k=1000000$ there are $1999$ iterations.

Comment: In your image link, $n$ is the initial value of "$k$", and the $O(\sqrt n)$ refers to that initial value. However the remark of "if $k\le\frac 14n^2$ then $k-\lceil\sqrt k\rceil\le\frac 14(n-1)^2$" should be applied to something else than that initial $n$. Let $N\approx\sqrt{2n}$, then $n\le\frac 14N^2$. If you iterate $K$ times, you get $f^K(n)\le\frac 14(N-K)^2$. So when $K$ reaches $N$, you're guaranteed that you've reached $0$. So the complexity is $O(N)=O(\sqrt n)$, with $n$ the initial value.

Comment: Would it be possible to expand more on how you got that the iteration gives   $f^K(n)≤\frac{1}{4}(N−K)^2$?